# Implementing a Pythonic "i, j" style for loop in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is an elegant, Pythonic solution to implementing a C-Style 'i, j' for loop in Python? Here's an example loop:

```cpp
for (i = 0, j = list.length - 1; i < list.length; j = i++ ){
    // Do stuff
}
```

I've encountered a few scenarios now where I would find this type of loop to be useful. However, I can't seem to find an elegant and Pythonic solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you think you need such a loop in the first place? You'd normally iterate *directly* over the loop.

Comment: Depends on what you need it for, but `itertools.tee` is great, `zip(lst, lst[1:])` if you don't care that you're making a copy of (most of) your list, etc.

Comment: And what does `j` range over here? You start at `length - 1` but then set `j` to `i` before the increment. So you are looping over the *previous* element? Just use a separate `previous` value then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, but I need to be able to loop over the same loop twice, but using the `j = i++` part of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python you could just track the previous element:

```
previous = lst[-1]           # j = len(lst) - 1
for current in lst:          # i = 0; i < len(lst); i++
    print current, previous  # lst[i], lst[j]
    # do stuff
    previous = current       # j = i before incrementing
```

Here `current` ranges over `lst[0]` to `lst[-1]`, and `previous` starts out with `lst[-1]` then 'trails' `current` via `lst[0]` through to `lst[-2]`.

You rarely need a loop over indices in Python, try to stick with looping over the iterable directly.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python supports negative list indices (`lst[-1] == lst[len(lst) - 1]`), that is not much different than iterating a list by single index:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,5,7,11,13]

>>> for i in range(len(lst)):
...     print(lst[i], lst[i-1])
...
1 13
2 1
3 2
5 3
7 5
11 7
13 11
```

If you don't mind making a copy of the list using slices, you can also use `zip()` to access list items in adjacent pairs:

```
>>> for cur, prev in zip(lst, lst[-1:]+lst):
...     print(cur, prev)
...
1 13
2 1
3 2
5 3
7 5
11 7
13 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one would be the the closest implementation to your code snippet

```
for i, j in enumerate(range(1, len(YOUR_LIST)), start=0):
    # do your stuff
    # i == 0, j == 1 at first itteration
    print(YOUR_LIST[i], YOUR_LIST[j])
```